# Overlapping FrameLayout Android

Tags: android

I don't know whats the problem on this. From the link Image its overlapping on screen which ruin my multiple `EditText`. I don't know what to do why its overlpping. Can you guys help me?

Sample:

[image]

Here's the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <!--&lt;!&ndash; The main content view where fragments are loaded &ndash;&gt;-->

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```